# Lowering volume on iphone 4 when button is broken

Tags: iphone

My iphone 4 volume button is broken.  Is there another way to lower the volume of streaming music and/ or videos?

Comment: What player are you using. It might have the on screen volume control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-click the home button (to show recently used applications) and swipe the bottom toolbar to the right twice. The first swipe will show you playback controls, the second one volume controls.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the remote on the headphones !

Answer (score 0):

Get something like [Activator](http://www.imore.com/activator-assign-custom-gestures-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-jailbreak-tip) and set it up.

Using the set up gestures you can control your volume on screen.